# What are the requirements for using Mercurial with Netbeans?

Tags: mercurial, netbeans-7

Background:
I want to check-out the source code from [Cliche](http://code.google.com/p/cliche/source/checkout), which is stored in a Mercurial repository. I use NetBeans 7 with JDK 1.7 on Windows, but have no experience with Mercurial. I only want to get the source code, further usage of Mercurial is not required.

**Question: What software / plug-in, etc. do I need to install, if any, to perform the above task?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the installation process and first checkout in: "[Mercurial User Guide](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html)". 
(You need to install [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) itself  first)

[image: hg checkout]

And more on Mercurial used from Netbeans on "[NetBeans + Mercurial Training](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HgTrainingMaterials)".